# Класс Bitrix\Main\ORM

Tags: php, база-данных, веб-программирование, битрикс, orm

На [ORM](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=05748&LESSON_PATH=3913.3516.5748) используются следующие **классы**

1. Cущности (Bitrix\Main\Entity\Base);
2. Поля сущностей (Bitrix\Main\Entity\Field и его наследники);
3. Датаменеджер (Bitrix\Main\Entity\DataManager).

В других местах я видел использование `\Bitrix\Main\ORM`. В чем разница между `\Bitrix\Main\Entity\` и `\Bitrix\Main\ORM\`? Пытался искать [разница между bitrix/main/orm и bitrix/main/entity](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20bitrix%2Fmain%2Form%20%D0%B8%20bitrix%2Fmain%2Fentity&sca_esv=584893833&sxsrf=AM9HkKmqci0Wt-IlDNE1VF6PUorJ3M2JiQ%3A1700758790629&ei=BoVfZfuGJvWpwPAPsO6QoAI&ved=0ahUKEwj7ocGczNqCAxX1FBAIHTA3BCQQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20bitrix%2Fmain%2Form%20%D0%B8%20bitrix%2Fmain%2Fentity&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiP9GA0LDQt9C90LjRhtCwINC80LXQttC00YMgYml0cml4L21haW4vb3JtINC4IGJpdHJpeC9tYWluL2VudGl0eTIIEAAYgAQYogQyCBAAGIAEGKIEMggQABiABBiiBDIIEAAYgAQYogQyCBAAGIAEGKIESJm8AVCqCFjKsAFwBXgBkAEAmAGXA6AB4RiqAQgwLjIyLjQtMbgBA8gBAPgBAcICChAAGEcY1gQYsAPCAgUQIRigAcICCRAhGKABGAoYKsICBxAhGKABGArCAggQABiJBRiiBOIDBBgAIEGIBgGQBgg&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1), [класс bitrix\main\orm](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%20bitrix%5Cmain%5Corm&sca_esv=584893833&sxsrf=AM9HkKlBdF9K8KrqfgfBxQoQrBTLXAKDTg%3A1700758940095&ei=nIVfZbm0Bf2HwPAP3byIiAg&ved=0ahUKEwi58uPjzNqCAxX9AxAIHV0eAoEQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%20bitrix%5Cmain%5Corm&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiGtC60LvQsNGB0YEgYml0cml4XG1haW5cb3JtMgQQIxgnSP4oUIcSWOwhcAF4AZABAJgBlAGgAYYFqgEDMi40uAEDyAEA-AEBwgIHECMYsAMYJ8ICChAAGEcY1gQYsAPCAgcQIxiwAhgnwgIHEAAYgAQYDcICDBAhGKABGMMEGAoYKuIDBBgAIEGIBgGQBgk&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) - не нашел инфы по классу `\Bitrix\Main\ORM`.

Comment: До версии 18.0.2 было \Bitrix\Main\Entity\, после -  \Bitrix\Main\ORM\.

Comment: @ВикторКарев а где вы нашли это сведение? Киньте ссылку. Спрашиваю, потому что инфы по  `\Bitrix\Main\ORM` не нашел в инете.

Comment: Официально - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/iblock/sectiontable/index.php, а вообще-то я веду кучу сайтов на битрикс, у многих старые версии, и действительно, после 18-й версии названия неймспейсов сменились.

Comment: Очень любопытен в этом отношении файл /bitrix/modules/main/include/compatibility.php.